# DateTime is not formatted properly / Time is being Truncated

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I need help because I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Initial setup:

```
MS Access database (.mdb). 
MS Office 2010 installed. 
MS SQL Server 2008
```

I built the routine to sync records from MS SQL Server 2008 to MS Access database. Tables are identical when it comes to table layout and number of fields

The part of the routine  there is an `INSERT SQL` statement

and part of SQL statement this code

```
//Query to execute
cmdToExecute.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + 
     "(EquipmentID, TimeInspected) VALUES(" +
     "'" + this._strEquipmentId.ToString() + "'," +
     "'" + this._dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt") + "'";
```

`_stTimeInspected` is declared as `sqlDateTime`.

For some reason I cannot get Date and Time together in MS Access database table.

When I use the format like `this._dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` I can get date, or 
`this._dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")` I can get Time

but for some reason time is being truncated when I use this: `_dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")`

I even try to use parametrized query

```
PARAMETERS [@EquipmentID] Text ( 255 ),  [@TimeInspected] DateTime;
INSERT INTO VisualInspectionHistory ( EquipmentID, , DateInspected, TimeInspected, RecordIsUpdated, DateSync, TimeSync )
SELECT [@EquipmentID] AS Expr1,  [@TimeInspected] AS Expr2

    /// <summary>
    /// Purpose: Insert new record into database table
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public override bool Insert()
    {

        OleDbCommand cmdToExecute = new OleDbCommand();
        cmdToExecute.CommandText = "VisualInspection_Insert";
        cmdToExecute.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmdToExecute.Connection = conMainConnection;

        try
        {

            cmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EquipmentID", (OleDbType)OleDbType.VarChar, 25)).Value = _strEquipmentID.ToString();
            cmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TimeInspected", (OleDbType)OleDbType.Date)).Value = (DateTime)(_dtTimeInspected);


            if (bMainConnectionIsCreatedLocal)
            {
                //Open connction
                conMainConnection.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                if (cpMainConnectionProvider.IsTransactionPending)
                {
                    cmdToExecute.Transaction = cpMainConnectionProvider.CurrentTransaction;
                }
            }

            //Execute query
            iRowsAffected = cmdToExecute.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            //Some error occured. Bubble it to caller and encapsulate Exception object
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Some error occured. Bubble it to caller and encapsulate Exception object
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bMainConnectionIsCreatedLocal == true)
            {
                //Close connection
                conMainConnection.Close();
            }
            cmdToExecute.Dispose();


        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not use parameterized SQL? That way you'd avoid all the conversion in the first place...

Comment: I tried that. I created query in MS Access database.The same result

Comment: I wasn't suggesting creating the query within MS Access... I was suggesting using a query with parameters, which is very different.

Comment: OK here is the code I was using cmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TimeInspected", (OleDbType)OleDbType.Date)).Value = (DateTime)_dtTimeInspected; this is just part of the code. Because there are 20 other fields in database table.

Comment: It would be better to put that in your *question* - and explain what happened when you tried it. It would also help if you'd show the type of the TimeInspected field.

Comment: When I hard coded the date something like this '12/24/2011 10:37:67 AM' it works

Comment: Using a string representation is almost *never* a good idea. But notice how you're using `/` in your sample string, but `-` in your format string...

Comment: Here parametrized query PARAMETERS [@EquipmentID] Text ( 255 ),[@TimeInspected] DateTime;
INSERT INTO VisualInspectionHistory ( EquipmentID, TimeInspected)
SELECT [@EquipmentID] AS Expr1,  [@TimeInspected]  AS Expr2

Comment: As I've said before, edit that into your *question* - along with details of your schema. You shouldn't need the "PARAMETERS" part as far as I'm aware... but it's a long time since I've done anything with Access, admittedly...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

To insert Date and time
    `//Query to execute
     cmdToExecute.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + 
     "(EquipmentID, TimeInspected) VALUES(" +
     "'" + this._strEquipmentId.ToString() + "'," +
     "#" + this._dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt") + "#";`
 
even without parametrized procedures

To insert time

```
`//Query to execute
 cmdToExecute.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + 
 "(EquipmentID, TimeInspected) VALUES(" +
 "'" + this._strEquipmentId.ToString() + "'," +
 "#" + this._dtTimeInspected.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") + "#";`
```

Thank you for your help